# Wait Cursor in VSTO word add-in application

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in

I am creating a VSTO word add in. i'm starting a long elaboration from ThisAddin and i would like to change the cursor to WaitCursor, so if I go to Globals.ThisAddIn.Application, there is no cursor property and i've tried with `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;` when starting the elaboration, and `Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;` at the end of the elaboration, but doesn't work, the cursor doesn't change.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Do you have a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 5):

```
private static void SetCursorToWaiting()
{
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
   application.System.Cursor = wdCursorWait;
}
private static void SetCursorToDefault()
{
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
   application.System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal;
}
```

Comment: For Excel, there is a property `Cursor` on the `Application` object: `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Cursor = XlMousePointer.xlWait;`

Answer (score -2):

Try the [Mouse.OverrideCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor(v=vs.110).aspx). Here are the [possible options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.cursors(v=vs.110).aspx).