# VSTO Outlook Mouse pointer change

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Working on an Outlook VSTO Add-In. I am trying to change the mouse pointer to reflect that an action is performed in the background. I tested the following code:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
```

---

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
```

---

[Wait Cursor in VSTO word add-in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241030/wait-cursor-in-vsto-word-add-in-application)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
app.System.Cursor = wdCursorWait; // --> app.System does not exist + No OutlookCursor :-/
```

Any clue?

Comment: I have not had any significant issues with `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor` aside from it sometimes getting unset by Word (not Outlook). What problems are you seeing?

Answer (score -1):

please try one of the bellow to solve your problem and let me know the result.

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

Or

```
 this.UseWaitCursor = true;
```

Or

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

Or

```
Application.UseWaitCursor = true;
```

Or

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
```

Comment: Non of them working while clickng button from ribbon I am testing in outlook 2016

Answer (score -1):

You need to import Word.DLL and then use the following code

```
            Outlook.Inspector currentInspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
            Word.Document document = currentInspector.WordEditor;
            Word.Application wordApp = document.Application;
            wordApp.System.Cursor = Word.WdCursorType.wdCursorWait;
            //perform your task
           //Switch to default Cursor 
           wordApp.System.Cursor = Word.WdCursorType.wdCursorNormal;
```

Comment: Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector() returns null