# How change Mouse pointer in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am trying to upload a file to a remote server using a custom button in outlook ribbon. Following steps are happened

1. Users click the upload file button in the ribbon and the File picker dialog is seen.
2. File selection popup will be seen and user select one or more files
3. After click ok button, I just want to change the default cursor to wait for the cursor
4. Once file uploading is complete, I tried to restore default curosor

My code is like following

```
 public void UploadFiles(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
      OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
          //some code which will call rest API to upload file 
           Cursor.Current = Cursors.default
        }
     }
```

But above code is not changing curosor. The button is present in compose window of outlook

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait Cursor in VSTO word add-in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241030/wait-cursor-in-vsto-word-add-in-application)

Comment: No, It is not answer, I am trying to do in Outlook not word

Comment: Ah i see. Did you try changing it to Outlook? i.e.: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.

Comment: Sir, there is not anything available application.System.Cursor property in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. I have already tried a full day today before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import Word.DLL and then use the following code

```
 public void UploadFiles(Office.IRibbonControl control)
  {
     OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
            Outlook.Inspector currentInspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
            Word.Document document = currentInspector.WordEditor;
            Word.Application wordApp = document.Application;
            wordApp.System.Cursor = Word.WdCursorType.wdCursorWait;
            //perform your task
           //Switch to default Cursor 
           wordApp.System.Cursor = Word.WdCursorType.wdCursorNormal; 

 }
 }
```